# Remove Green Sections in WindowBuilder Pro JFrame on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, windowbuilder

I have created a `JFrame`, and all I want in it is a label and a slider (very simple GUI). But WindowBuilder plugin for Eclipse gives me these weird sections that I haven't asked for and I've no idea how to get rid of them and re-size my `JFrame`. Dragging doesn't seem to work.

[image]

How can I remove them green sections (North, West, Centre .. etc) and re-size my JFrame so it nicely wrap around the `JSlider` that I'll be placing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am facing the same problem as you! But I played around with it, turns out that you could add an "Absolute layout" under layouts, then you're free to place where you want your items to be! :)